# Less precise time measurement for use in a chart

Tags: c#, winforms

I am timing the running of several different methods of sorting (insertion, merge, heap) in C# and am trying to display that measurement in a chart for comparison. I am using this to time the methods

```
DateTime utc3 = DateTime.UtcNow;
SortArray(mergeSortArray, 0, mergeSortArray.Length-1);
DateTime utc4 = DateTime.UtcNow;
TimeSpan Time2 = utc4 - utc3;
DateTime chartTime3 = Convert.ToDateTime(Time3.ToString());
```

But the chart function will not take timespan as an input so I have to change it to DateTime to get it to display.

However when I run the smaller amounts of numbers like 100 or 1000, I'm getting numbers like 00:00:00.054209 which is displaying on the graph as 54,209 rather than a fraction of a second. Because of this a sort that takes 5 seconds will display as a tiny bar at the bottom and the fractional second is really large. If I change the time to
`Time3.Seconds.ToString();`
the label displays 0 but the graph looks the same.
I have tried both `Time.Seconds` and `Time.Seconds.ToString()` in the convert to DateTime line and neither would work.

I'm not sure if I should adjust how I'm keeping time or how the graph represents the time or both. What is the best way to do this so that the bar graph shows the meaningful difference between the times?

Comment: Use [Stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.stopwatch.elapsedmilliseconds) instead.

Comment: ElapsedMiliseconds is also a TimeSpan object and the chart will not take it as input. I was unable to find anything in the documentation about converting it. Is it possible to convert it to a double or float?

Comment: The property is declared like this `public long ElapsedMilliseconds { get; }`. It returns a `long`. And `TimeSpan` has a [TotalMilliseconds Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timespan.totalmilliseconds) returning a `double`.